# Получить статус chassis intrusion из-под windows

Tags: windows, безопасность, железо, wmi

Возможно ли получить статус `chassis intrusion` из-под windows? Dell делает это с помощью `WMI`, они создают свой `namespace` и как-то записывают туда значение, а сами предоставляют скрипты для выборки из этих `namespace`. Я пробовал смотреть в `Win32_SystemEnclosure`, замыкая и размыкая `chassis intrusion`, но ничего не менялось.

Comment: Подозреваю, что это manufacturer dependent feature, т.е. функционал, предоставляемый только некоторыми производителями мат. плат (пример с температурой процессора: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756224/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-win32-temperatureprobe/759691#759691), в частности, Dell. Или вас интересует именно для Dell?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Наоборот, хочу сделать сам тоже самое, что сделали Dell

Comment: Подозреваю, что для этого нужно писать уже на низком уровне. Вы не пробовали написать в Dell?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov не думаю, что они ответят

Comment: Почему нет? Я успешно переписывался и переписываюсь с поддержкой многих производителей разного железа. Если технология не защищена патентом и не является ноу-хау, ей могут и поделиться. Только будьте вежливыми и ведите себя как клиент их компании :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробовал поиграться с классом WMI Win32_SystemEnclosure. Так вот, при закрытом корпусе (у меня теперь есть датчик на новом корпусе :) ) запрос wmiServices.InstancesOf Win32_SystemEnclosure выдаёт (привожу только относящиеся к делу инстансы):

```
SecurityBreach=3
BreachDescription = NULL
SecurityStatus = 3
```

Если же открываю корпус, то, в зависимости от того, далеко ли крышка от датчика:

```
SecurityBreach=4 или 5
BreachDescription = "Alert" или "Intrusion"
SecurityStatus =1
```

Так что вот вам и ответ. У меня не Dell. Мать Asus, производитель корпуса, подозреваю, не при чём.